# Google Maps V3: polygon vertices

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

Does anybody know how to get an array of the vertices of a polygon built using the new drawing library?
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html

I have tried with `newShape.getPath().getArray()[0].lat()`, but this seems to be empty

Comment: can you post your complete Code? I have the same problem to save a polygon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't have any problem with `newShape.getPath().getArray()[0].lat()`. If `newShape` polygon object is not null and the vertices weren't removed from the path, it should work.

You can also try `newShape.getPath().getAt(0).lat()`, it should work as well.

There must be some other problem in your code.